# Configured Azure Bastion service for VM, when I am trying to connect it is always showing connection error and bastion service appears unstable

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-bastion

Configured Azure Bastion service for VM, when I am trying to connect through Bastion service it is always showing connection error and bastion service appears unstable, and it is showing the target machine is either currently unreachable or username/password is not correct. Please re-verify your credentials. But I used correct credentials.

Can anyone give solution or advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After getting above errors I have troubleshot as well there is no blockage from connectivity from VM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Bation, I advise you to connect with SSH.
You have the open the 22 port and then, open your terminal.
You can enter your username and finally your pasword.
To connect in SSH is a secure option too like bastion.

Regards